# drag image from desktop and convert into base64 in ckeditor not worked in chrome

Tags: ckeditor

We can just drag the image from desktop and covert into base64 directly in ckeditor.

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f6put/).

```
   CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
```

But it seems not worked in Chrome and only works in firefox.

Is there any method to do the same thing in chrome?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

CKEditor using ImagePaste plugin it work only for Firefox.

You can try with doksoft_image_embed plugin. See demo here:

http://doksoft.com/soft/ckeditor-image-embed/demo.html

Unfortunately this plugin is Commercial License.

Or you can try with Base64 Image:

- Base64 Image will replace ImagePaste, Button Upload image as base64 into CKEditor:

[image]

http://ckeditor.com/addon/base64image

.

Comment: I developed the ImagePaste plugin just to avoid the problems in Firefox due to the huge base64 images pasted into the content, so it's clear why it works that way only in Firefox (and why it's a wrong answer for this question). If you want a cross browser solution to upload files to the server (dragging, pasting or with a single click) then you can use the commercial SimpleUploads plugin that also has the option to embed data as base64 but it's strongly recommended not to do so.

Comment: how to do image size validation in base64?